# Driver [google] not supported

Tags: testing, laravel, codeception

I have an app that use google Auth to auth users, i'm trying to do some functional testing using codeception framework, but when i try to run the functional testing i got the following error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Driver [google] not supported.
```

Is there is any problem to define Google Auth in codeception or may be pass by it ? , it's working just fine with my application but it's not working in the testing
Here is my Auth config file

return array(

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Authentication Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the authentication driver that will be utilized.
| This driver manages the retrieval and authentication of the users
| attempting to get access to protected areas of your application.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'driver' => 'google',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Model
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
| Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
| is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
|
*/

'model' => 'User',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
| table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
| default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
|
*/

'table' => 'users',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Password Reminder Settings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the settings for password reminders, including a view
| that should be used as your password reminder e-mail. You will also
| be able to set the name of the table that holds the reset tokens.
|
| The "expire" time is the number of minutes that the reminder should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'reminder' => array(

    'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',

    'table' => 'password_reminders',

    'expire' => 60,

),
```

);

Also i tried to add the following in the _boostrap.php regarding the functional testing but still it can't pass the google driver, i think there is something wrong here .

```
Auth::LoginUsingId(1);
```

Comment: It says right there in the comment which drivers are supported. And you're surprised to get an error when you pick something else?

Comment: OK thanks for your comment but the google Auth working in my application, it's only not working in the testing

Comment: I don't really see the relevance of authentication in your application. You're trying to configure authentication in Codeception, no?

Comment: i'm just do some testing but it's require the user to be Authenticated, and i'm using google Auth for that

Comment: You're not listening.

Comment: Anyone else with problems, if installed a new package for the driver: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39261756/3758439